# Error with -c flag in implicit rule in Makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I'm learning makefile and I'm trying to reduce my makefile by using implicit rules. So far this is what I have:

```
CC = /usr/bin/g++
OBJECTS_INTERACTIVE = calcular.o calc_interactive.o
    
calc_interactive: $(OBJECTS_INTERACTIVE)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS_INTERACTIVE) -o $@              

calcular.o: calcular.c calcular.h
    $(CC) -c calcular.c

calc_interactive.o: calcular.h calc_interactive.c
    $(CC) -c calc_interactive.c
```

If I run it like that, no errors. However, I would like to use an implicit rule like `calcular.o: calcular.h`, which AFAIK is performing `g++ -c calcular.c` under the hood, **but apparently** it's performing that command without the `-c` flag, which I think it's the key, and I don't manage to make g++ to use the `-c` flag when using an implicit rule. This is what I would like to achieve:

```
CC = /usr/bin/g++
OBJECTS_INTERACTIVE = calcular.o calc_interactive.o

calc_interactive: $(OBJECTS_INTERACTIVE)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS_INTERACTIVE) -o $@  

calcular.o: calcular.h

calc_interactive.o: calcular.h
```

It yields this error:

```
jules@desktop:$ make
/usr/bin/g++ -c calc_interactive.c
/usr/bin/g++ calcular.o calc_interactive.o -o calc_interactive
g++: error: calcular.o: No such file or directory 
makefile:11: recipe for target 'calc_interactive' failed 
make: *** [calc_interactive] Error 1
```

**EDIT**: detailed pastebin of all files
https://pastebin.com/FZy5kqzj

Comment: Why are you running `g++` on a `.c` file?

Comment: The problem is not "running with `-c`".  If that had been the problem then you'd have gotten an error from trying to build the `calculator.o` file because it couldn't be linked.  The problem here is that the file `calculatior.o` doesn't even exist, and make didn't try to create it.  That means there's something wrong with your makefile.  However since you only showed us the version that works and didn't show us the version that fails, we can't really help you.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I was previously dealing with c++ and I changed to C.  I didn't think that changing the compiler will produce a different result because the files are very basic (functions with no more than prints)

Comment: Assuming the second `makefile` shown is causing the issue I don't understand how it can possibly generate the symptoms you're seeing.  From the output alone I'd guess there's a rule that tells `make` it rebuilds both `calcular.o` *and* `calc_interactive.o` but which actually only rebuilds `calc_interactive.o`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, do not compile C source with a C++ compiler, unless you're *sure* that it is written strictly in the common subset of those two languages.  C and C++ each have features the other lacks, and it is possible to write code that conforms to both languages but means different things to each.  Unless you're making a conscious and well-informed effort to write dual-language code, use a C compiler for C code.

In the second place, if `make`, using exactly this makefile:

> ```
> CC = /usr/bin/g++
> OBJECTS_INTERACTIVE = calcular.o calc_interactive.o
>
> calc_interactive: $(OBJECTS_INTERACTIVE)
>     $(CC) $(OBJECTS_INTERACTIVE) -o $@  
>
> calcular.o: calcular.h
>
> calc_interactive.o: calcular.h
> ```

produces the output you claim it does:

> ```
> jules@desktop:$ make
> /usr/bin/g++ -c calc_interactive.c
> /usr/bin/g++ calcular.o calc_interactive.o -o calc_interactive
> g++: error: calcular.o: No such file or directory 
> makefile:11: recipe for target 'calc_interactive' failed 
> make: *** [calc_interactive] Error 1
> ```

then the most likely conclusion is that `calcular.o` does not already exist, and there is no source file present from which `make` knows how to build it.  In particular, there is no `calcular.c`.  This would imply that the original makefile should no longer work, either.  Perhaps you accidentally deleted the source file, or introduced a spelling error into filename or makefile, or similar.

I suppose there is also an outside chance that `g++`'s error message is misleading.  If `calcular.o` already exists and is up to date, but its access-control properties prevent you from opening it for reading, then `make` would not try to rebuild it, but `g++` *might* issue a misleading diagnostic, where "No such file or directory" really means "I couldn't open such a file".  In that case, removing `calcular.o`, so that `make` needs to rebuild it, might be the cleanest solution.

Comment: I changed the compiler to GCC and it still produces a wrong output. I edited my OP with a pastebin with details of every file and I double-checked everything, still don't know what could be happening. I know that it may not be that important, but I was just trying to learn and I coulnd't figure it out why it wouldn't work.